# Selenium python not able to send_keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am automating scripts into selenium python,facing issue in sending keys in selenium searchbox.

code is as below:

```
contact_old=driver.find_element_by_class_name("consoleRelatedRecord")
time.sleep(2)

search_c=contact_old.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/section/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/one-record-home-flexipage2/forcegenerated-flexipage_rfq_default_rfq__c/flexipage-record-page-decorator/slot/flexipage-record-home-template-desktop2/div/div[2]/div[2]/slot/slot/flexipage-component2[1]/force-progressive-renderer/slot/slot/flexipage-aura-wrapper/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/input')

search_c.send_keys(contact_name)           
time.sleep(3)
```

The xpath is always changing , could you find a better way for send_keys in this SearchBOX?

```
<input class=" default input uiInput uiInputTextForAutocomplete uiInput--default uiInput--input uiInput uiAutocomplete uiInput--default uiInput--lookup" maxlength="500" role="combobox" id="2197:0" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" aria-describedby="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant="" data-aura-rendered-by="2239:0" data-aura-class="uiInput uiInputTextForAutocomplete uiInput--default uiInput--input uiInput uiAutocomplete uiInput--default uiInput--lookup" data-interactive-lib-uid="8" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Search contacts..." title="Search contacts...">
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below Xpath:

`//input[contains(@title,'Search contacts')]`

Or

`//input[@title='Search contacts...']`

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) enabled element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the _`element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.default.input.uiInput.uiInputTextForAutocomplete.uiInput--default.uiInput--input.uiInput.uiAutocomplete.uiInput--default.uiInput--lookup[title^='Search contacts'][placeholder^='Search contacts']"))).send_keys(contact_name)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class=' default input uiInput uiInputTextForAutocomplete uiInput--default uiInput--input uiInput uiAutocomplete uiInput--default uiInput--lookup' and starts-with(@title, 'Search contacts')][starts-with(@placeholder, 'Search contacts')]"))).send_keys(contact_name)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```